# Protractor with oracledb, after fetching value from oracle db unable to access the valu from other function

Tags: protractor, node-oracledb

i'm trying to write reusable function for fetch the value from oracledb and assign that value where ever required.

My sample code is below.
//getTtalRwCnt.js

```
'use strict';
var db_con = require('./oracleConnectPage.js');
// var db = new db_con();
var OracelQP = db_con.getOracleQP_details();
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var tmpRwCnt;

var getTtalRwCnt = function () {
    oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.ARRAY;
    var query = "SELECT TESTCASEID FROM EXECUTE_TESTCASE";
    oracledb.getConnection(OracelQP, function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message); return;
        }
        connection.execute(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message); 
                connection.close();
                return;
            }
            console.log("result----->" + result.rows.length);
            tmpRwCnt = result.rows.length;
            return tmpRwCnt;
        })
    })
}
module.exports.getTtalRwCnt = getTtalRwCnt();
```

//spec.js

```
    'use strict';
var rwCnt = require('../DBSample/DB/getTtalRwCnt.js');

describe('Get Total number of Rows from DB', function () {
  it('Get Rw count',function(){
    console.log(rwCnt.getTtalRwCnt());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issue in your code:

**1)** export wrong

```
module.exports.getTtalRwCnt = getTtalRwCnt();
```

should be

```
module.exports.getTtalRwCnt = getTtalRwCnt;
```

**2)** `tmpRwCnt` is the return value of callback function, not the return value of function `getTtalRwCnt`, additionally you not have return for function `getTtalRwCnt`.

To make value in callback function can be used outside callback, you can choose to use Promise solution.

```
'use strict';
var db_con = require('./oracleConnectPage.js');
// var db = new db_con();
var OracelQP = db_con.getOracleQP_details();
var oracledb = require('oracledb');

var getTtalRwCnt = function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.ARRAY;
        var query = "SELECT TESTCASEID FROM EXECUTE_TESTCASE";
        oracledb.getConnection(OracelQP, function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                reject(err);
            }
            connection.execute(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message); 
                    connection.close();
                    reject(err);
                }
                rwCnt = result.rows.length;
                console.log("result----->" + rwCnt);
                resolve(rwCnt);
            })
        })
    });

};

module.exports = getTtalRwCnt;
```

//spec.js

```
'use strict';
var getTtalRwCnt = require('../DBSample/DB/getTtalRwCnt.js');

describe('Get Total number of Rows from DB', function () {
  it('Get Rw count',function(){
    var totalRw = getTtalRwCnt();

    // If you use Jasmine or Chai
    totalRw.then(function(total){
        console.log('total row: ' + total);
        expect(total).toEqual(10);
    });

    // if you use Jasmine 
    expect(totalRw).toEqual(10);

    // if you use Chai and Chai-as-promise
    expect(totalRw).to.eventually.to.equal(10);
  });
});
```

Comment: It's very useful information and it's working fine thanks for the update and effort.

Comment: Without using totalRw.then() function is that possible to get the value directly.. like console.log(totalRw);

Comment: Is there any option to get the values directly without using .then() function. Like console.log(totalRw); or like for(crntrw=1; crntrw<=totalRw; crntrw++)

Comment: You can look into ES6 async/await, if you use it, you need to disable protractor control flow, because they are not compatible, from selenium release plan, protractor control flow will be disabled by replacing to async/await at  Oct 2018.  You need to add `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in protractor conf file to disable protracor control flow currently. detail: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#disabling-the-control-flow